# Stream audio from Bluetooth to default output on Android?

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, android-jetpack

How do I setup an Android application which streams audio from Bluetooth to the default output?

Basically, I just want to stream any audio coming in from an already connected Bluetooth device to the loudspeaker of the local device.

I can find examples on how to stream to a remote device, but here I want to do the opposite: listen to a connected device and just play it out loud.

I guess it's a rather simple operation... I have looked into Jetpack, but the more I look, the more confused I get.

Local OS is Android 10+